# Where do I find my table in MySQL after I run a Laravel migration using Homestead?

Tags: mysql, laravel, homestead

I am trying to create a "Basic Task List" according to the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart). After I run "php artisan migrate", I can see that that my tables were migrated successfully according to the console, which is Git Bash.

In phpmyadmin, the following databases are visible:

- homestead
- information_schema
- mysql
- performance_schema
- sys

However, I couldn't find my new "tasks" table anywhere in phpmyadmin. Where is my table located in mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in the **homestead** database.

Check your `.env` and `config/database.php` files and you'll see how your database is set.